# Cache dependency between two items in cache

Tags: asp.net, .net, caching

I have two items in cache. My requirement is to make one item in a cache dependent on another single item in same cache.

```
Cache["UserName"] = "Test User";
Cache["Message"] = "Test Message";
```

when `Cache["UserName"]` changes or is removed from the cache, `Cache["Message"]` should automatically be dropped/invalidated.

Using DateTime is not my requirement and neither any file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give your cache `keys` as an argument and it is supported by default in Asp.Net. Read this for more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cachedependency.aspx

or especially this one:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/818kahch.aspx

Giving a filename is not mandatory. Cache keys are just supported out of the box.

```
Cache["key1"] = "Value 1";

// Make key2 dependent on key1.
String[] dependencyKey = new String[1];
dependencyKey[0] = "key1";
CacheDependency dependency = new CacheDependency(null, dependencyKey);

Cache.Insert("key2", "Value 2", dependency);
```

Comment: So, Can I Do like this: String[] dependencyKey = new String[2]; and specify the second key later on in any other function ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that as it takes an array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Cache["UserName"] = "Test User";

// Make Cache["Message"] dependent on Cache["UserName"].
string[] dependencyKey = new string[1];
dependencyKey[0] = "UserName";

CacheDependency dependency = new CacheDependency(null, dependencyKey);
Cache.Insert("Message", "Test Message", dependency);
```